# Very strange overflow+float behavior

Tags: css, css-float

HTML:

```
<div id="float_left">
    DIV1
  </div>   
  <div id="without_overflow">
    DIV2 
  </div>
```

css:

```
#float_left{
      float: left;
      width:200px;
      background-color: red; 
    }
    #without_overflow{
      width:400px;  
      height:40px;
      background-color:green;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kgypo14y/1

The result of the above code is what I expected. However, if I added overflow:auto or overflow:hidden to the second div the result is totally unexpected to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/60nzadLz/2/

Do you have a good explanation for that?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those values of `overflow` cause the element to establish a new block formatting context. A float may never intrude another block formatting context, so the entire element is shifted away from the float. From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space.